# Euler Complexification Help.

Tags: calculus

We have$$e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$$

I want

$$\begin{align}
I&=\large\int \underbrace{\sin x}_{\large\Im e^{ix}}\quad e^{\pi x}\,\mathrm dx \\
&=\int e^{ix}e^{\pi x}dx\\
&=\int e^{(i+\pi) x}dx\\
&=\frac{e^{(i+\pi) x}}{(i+\pi)}\\
&=\frac{\pi-i}{\pi^2+1}e^{\pi x}(\cos x +i\sin x)\\
&=\color{blue}{\frac{1}{\pi^2+1}e^{\pi x}(\pi-i)(\cos x +i\sin x)}\\
&I=\color{blue}{\Im\left(\frac{1}{\pi^2+1}e^{\pi x}(\pi\sin x-\cos)\right)}\\
\end{align}$$

Please explain how my teacher distributed the Pi-i (circled in blue).

[image: http://s16.postimg.org/t8b86m1hx/Capture_50_1.jpg]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “The Pi-i”?

Comment: I will salute the one who "latexifies" this question.

Comment: I'm $\LaTeX$-ifying  this, Please Don't make edits.

Comment: I've already been working on it. Almost done.

Comment: Please take note that removing the image will make the question trivial.

Comment: Damn, I have to improve my $\LaTeX$ing speed!

Comment: @Integrator You're kidding right? You're just too kind. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

$$\begin{align}
I
&=\int e^{\pi x}\sin x\,\mathrm dx\\
&=\Im\int e^{(\pi+i) x}\,\mathrm dx\\
&=\color{blue}{\Im}\frac{e^{\pi x}}{\pi^2+1}(\pi-i)(\cos x+i\sin x)\\
&=\color{blue}{\Im}\frac{e^{\pi x}}{\pi^2+1}\left({\pi\cos x}+i\color{blue}{\pi\sin x}-i\color{blue}{\cos x}+{\sin x}\right)\\
&=\frac{e^{\pi x}}{\pi^2+1}\left(\color{blue}{\pi\sin x}-\color{blue}{\cos x}\right)\\
\end{align}$$

> $$\large \int e^{\pi x}\sin x\,\mathrm dx=\frac{e^{\pi x}}{\pi^2+1}\left({\pi\sin x}-{\cos x}\right)$$